# How can I calculate the determinant without knowing every element of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I was given the following matrix and asked only to find the determinant. As far as I know we need to know every element of the matrix in order to do that. But maybe I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It dawns on me that the dot-dot-dots may seem to the poster as unstated elements of the matrix. But that would be wrong. They indicate that the obvious pattern is to be continued: If it's an n × n matrix, then each matrix entry M(i,j) is equal to 1 if i+j = n+1 and equal to 0 otherwise. So M has 1's on its anti-diagonal and 0's elsewhere.

Comment: All entries of the matrix are given. The dots mean "continue the same pattern".

Comment: Swapping rows reverses the sign. So swap all the rows until it's the identity matrix and you'll get a determinant of $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 2):

First, as noted above, the problem statement actually gives you all the elements: it is implied that the matrix has $1$ at the main skew diagonal and 0 everywhere else.

Second, you can formally prove that the answer is given by the recurrence: denote as $d_{n}$ the value of determinant of $n$-th matrix of the form indicated in the problem statement. Then
$$d_{1}=1$$
$$d_{n}=(-1)^{n-1}d_{n-1}$$
Indeed, perform the Laplace expansion of the determinant by the last column. The only nonzero term will be exactly $(-1)^{k-1}d_{n-1}$. This is a linear recurrence of the first order. There are many ways to solve such recurrences, my favorite is the method of generating function. Consider the function (or, in general, the formal power series) defined by the power series expansion
$$D(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}d_{n}z^{n}=d_0 + d_1 \cdot z + d_2 \cdot z^2 + \cdots $$

Choose, for convenience, $d_{0}=1$ (this won't break the recurrence: $d_{1}=(-1)^{1-1}d_{0}=(-1)^{0}1=1$). Then multiply both parts of the recurrence by $z^{n}$:
$$d_{n}z^{n}=(-1)^{n-1}d_{n-1}z^{n}$$
Sum over all $n$'s for which the expression on both sides makes sense:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}d_{n}z^{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{(n-1)}d_{n-1}z^{n}$$

On the left hand side, we have $D(z)-d_{0}=D(z)-1$. On the right hand side, we have $zD(-z)$. Therefore, we obtain an equation on the generating function $D(z)$:
$$D(z)-1=zD(-z)$$
with the condition that $D(0)=1$ (since $D(0)$ is the value of the zeroth coefficient of the power series). Hence
$$\frac{D(z)-1}{z}=D(-z)$$
Then, changing $-z\to z$ in both sides, we obtain
$$\frac{D(-z)-1}{-z}=\frac{1-D(-z)}{z}=D(z)$$
At the other hand,
$$D(z)=zD(-z)+1$$
Hence,
$$zD(-z)+1=\frac{1-D(-z)}{z}$$
$$z^2D(-z)+z=1-D(-z)$$
$$z^2D(z)-z=1-D(z)$$
and we have a linear equation on $D(z)$:
$$z^2D(z)+D(z)=1+z$$
$$D(z)=\frac{1+z}{z^2+1}$$
We've obtained the generating function. Remember that we defined it as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}d_{n}z^{n}$
Hence, to obtain the explicit formula for $d_n$, all we need is to obtain the coefficient before the $n$-th term of the Taylor series of this function. To do that, it is essential to remember the following simple formula:
$$\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+...$$
This identity is true only when $|z|<1$, if we consider it as a functional identity, but it is convenient to consider it as the *definition* of the generating function $\frac{1}{1-z}$ as a formal power series: it has the same algebraic properties in the ring of formal power series, as $\frac{1}{1-z}$ has in the ring of analytic functions on the domain $|z|<1$. Then
$$\frac{1}{1+z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}z^{2n}$$
and
$$\frac{1+z}{1+z^2}= \frac{1}{1+z^2}+\frac{z}{1+z^2} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}z^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}z^{2n+1}$$.
Hence, the even coefficients of the Taylor series of $D(z)$ are $+1, -1, +1, ...$, and the odd coefficients are $+1, -1, +1, -1, \cdots$, as expected.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not the best idea to solve a question for the O.P. when they have not asked for such complete help. In this case the question asked only to clarify whether one can calculate a determinant of a matrix without knowing all its entries, and gave an example. The question just needed that example clarified and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix $A\in\mathbb F^{n\times n}$ is an involution, i.e. $A^2=I$ (check: it is a symmetric permutation matrix), so all eigenvalues are $\in\big\{-1,1\big\}$.

If $n$ is **even** then $n=2r$ so
$A=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0 & I_r \\  I_r & \mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}\implies \det\big(A\big)=(-1)^r$ since  $\text{trace}\big(A\big)=0$
i.e. this implies $A$ has $r$ eigenvalues $=1$ and $r$ eigenvalues $=-1$ (why?).

If $n$ is **odd** then $n=2r+1$,
$\implies \det\big(A\big)=(-1)^r$ since $\text{trace}\big(A\big)=1$
i.e. by the matrix setup of 0's and 1's we know $\text{trace}\big(A\big)\in \big\{0,1\big\}$ but trace of $0$ would imply $\frac{2r+1}{2}$ eigenvalues of 1 and $\frac{2r+1}{2}$ eigenvalues of $-1$ which is impossible. So $\text{trace}\big(A\big)=1 \implies A$ has $r+1$ eigenvalues $=1$ and $r$ eigenvalues $=-1$.

Comment: Or (maybe more directly?), swap the rows $1$ and $n$, $2$ and $n-1$, etc. to get the identity, whose determinant is $1$. If $n=2r$ there are $r$ swaps hence $(-1)^r$, and if $n=2r+1$ there are $r$ swaps as well, so again $(-1)^r$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes, I think you could swap rows $1$ and $n$, leaving you with a block diagonal matrix, then immediately call on an induction hypothesis. A bit shorter, though using the trace to get the determinant has a certain charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the pattern continues - 1's on the lower-left-upper-right diagonal and 0's everywhere else.  Since the only nonzero product is the lower-left-upper-right diagonal, and that gets subtracted, the determinant is -1.  (Try it with square matrices of various sizes on a calculator.)

Comment: I don't think it is always $-1$. I think for the matrix $A_{k}$ of the size $k$ it is $ (-1)^{k-1} \cdot \det A_{k-1}$ , you can show that using the Laplace expansion in the last column. For $k=2$ and $k=3$ this gives $-1$, but already for $k=4$ you have $-1^{3}\cdot -1=1$. Generally it alternates between $1$ and $-1$ with period 4: $1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, \cdots$

Comment: For example, if the matrix in the question were of size 1 × 1, the determinant would not equal -1.